# How to solve [Error: got "map", expected "array"] while my YAML seems right

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm

I have a yaml file shown thus:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    apiVersion: v1
    type: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: {{.Values.features.persistence.name}}
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: {{.Values.features.persistence.size}}
          storageClassName: {{.Values.features.persistence.storageClass}}
          volumeMode: Filesystem
  {{- end}}
```

I have tried to correct all I can but still not getting any headway. When I try to deploy the file, it gives the error below:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec.volumeClaimTemplates): invalid type for io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetSpec.volumeClaimTemplates: got "map", expected "array"
make: *** [upgrade] Error 1
```

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite obvious from the message you get: `volumeClaimTemplates` must contain an array but you supply a map. The simple fix is to add `-` here:

```yaml
volumeClaimTemplates:
- apiVersion: v1
  type: PersistentVolumeClaim
  # ...
```

Now the previous content is an item in a sequence.

Comment: I have tried this but it returns an error about affinity. ```unknown field "affinity" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec``` @flyx

Comment: Maybe the indentation is not right. The field `affinity` shouldn't be in the `volumeClaimTemplates`.

Comment: @Aro Your input does not show a key `affinity`. It seems this error does not come from the snippet you show. I know this is frustrating, but if the error you inquired about is gone, you should mark this question as solved and create a new question showing the newly relevant snippet and error message. Commenting on this answer with a new error vastly reduces the people you reach, and I might not be proficient enough to help you with follow-up errors.